# Difference between Branch.io validateReferralCode() and applyReferralCode()?

Tags: android, referrals, branch.io

I am using Branch.io for referral codes. I see two methods that seem applicable to what I would like to do, however, the description of both seem identical. In the context of Branch.io, how do I confirm that a user has entered in a proper referral code?

Branch documentation: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branch-Android-SDK#register-an-activity-for-direct-deep-linking-optional-but-recommended

According to the documentation there are two methods that can work, validateReferralCode() and applyReferralCode(). The implementation for both are as follows.

```
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
branch.validateReferralCode(code, new BranchReferralInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referralCode, Branch.BranchError error) {
        try {
            if (!referralCode.has("error_message")) {       // will change to using a second callback parameter for error code soon!
                String referral_code = referralCode.getString("referral_code");
                if (referral_code.equals(code)) {
                    // valid
                } else {
                    // invalid (should never happen)
                }
            } else {
                // invalid
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

And....

```
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
branch.applyReferralCode(code, new BranchReferralInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referralCode, Branch.BranchError error) {
        try {
            if (!referralCode.has("error_message")) {
                // applied. you can get the referral code amount from the referralCode JSONObject and deduct it in your UI.
            } else {
                // invalid code
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

The description in the documentation reads as,

> Validate referral code
>
> Validate if a referral code exists in Branch system and is still
>   valid. A code is vaild if:
>
> It hasn't expired. If its calculation type is uniqe, it hasn't been
>   applied by current user. If valid, returns the referral code
>   JSONObject in the call back.

And for apply referral code

> Apply referral code
>
> Apply a referral code if it exists in Branch system and is still valid
>   (see above). If the code is valid, returns the referral code
>   JSONObject in the call back.

What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Branch's system, you can specify a referral code to be one time use (meaning someone called apply earlier). If you need to look this value up before hand, you use the Validate referral code method.

Apply, of course, applies the code to a user's balance. If you've created a referral code of type unique, then Apply will fail. It's good practice to validate a code first before presenting to a user or applying a code.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines. Thanks!